# Evaluate Google Sheet offline programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api

What's the best way to evaluate a Google Sheet without using the API? By evaluate I mean, change some cells and recompute the dependent cells.

You can use Google Sheets offline, so they have to be stored somewhere and the evaluation code also needs to run offline. How can I control this functionality from JS/Python?

I need to run thousands of computations as quickly as possible and the API would be too slow for this / I would get rate limited.

Answer (score 1):

> *You can use Google Sheets offline, so they have to be stored somewhere and the evaluation code also needs to run offline. How can I control this functionality from JS/Python?*

For offline support the data must be stored by the browser.

You can use the browser's Developer console to inspect the data-stores supported by that browser (ie. IndexedDB, Local Storage, Web SQL, etc.). From what I can see from Google Chrome (go to your developer console and select the Application tab), you can find some google docs data mirrored in IndexedDB databases.

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can interact with that data in any meaningful way outside of the dev console. Plus some of that data appears to be encrypted.

If your goal is to use Google Sheets as a analytics platform to perform heavy computation then you're in for a lot of disappointment. As you're no doubt discovering Google Sheets are bound by a number of limitations and its not meant to be used in that capacity. You probably need something more robust and that means moving to more traditional database solutions, but they wont' be free.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using normal formulas, [this documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#) will show you the basics on how to use them for regular data management in the Sheet.

After that, you should see [this list of functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46977?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#) to know what tools you have available to create the functionality that you want.

Lastly, you should see [this tutorial](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/creating-simple-formulas/1/) on creating your own formulas, it can be helpful to expand what the normal functions can do and have a more tailored solution to your needs.